# How did the QWERTY keyboard came?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

How did the QWERTY keyboard came? Does this keyboard layout has any logical explanation?

Comment: did you try to google your question first ? http://www.google.fr/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=why+the+qwerty+keyboard

Comment: @JMax: if anyone was RTFM/using google/doing meditation before asking here, I'm quite sure there was just a few questions...

Comment: @dag Sometimes it's different coming up with the terminology to be able to search for something. Other times, the amount of referenced documentation to sift through and for a simple question is mind-boggling. You might also simply not even *understand* the explanations given. But apparently, of this is the case here though.

Comment: @daniel-beckin fact that's what happened.I looked into, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWERTY page and didn't find what i was looking for.

Comment: The first two sentences of the Wikipedia page you apparently cite answers the questions completely

Comment: I didn't find "frequently used letters would not be adjacent to another" in the first 2 lines of the page I linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inventor of the typewriter checked letter-pair frequency, and arranged the keyboard of his invention [so that frequently used letters would not be adjacent to another](http://home.earthlink.net/~dcrehr/whyqwert.html). This helped to avoid the typebars of the typewriter from sticking to one another and then jamming. For example, "th" is a commonly used combination, and he wanted those two letters to lie apart from each other.